# VBA Help - If a Column contains a specific letter, make another column a negative number then loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make this code loop to catch every row that has data in it in my excel file.

The code below looks at Column L, and if the cell in column L has a "D" then the value in column H in the same row will be multiplied by -1.

This code works for the cells in L5 and H5, but I am struggling trying to figure out how to loop this, so after these cells it would look at L6 and H6...and then keep going through the loop until there are no more values in column L. Can someone help with this? I'm not great with loops. Code is below. Thank you!!

```
Sub NewCode()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

If ws.Range("L5") = D Then

Else

ws.Range("H5") = ws.Range("H5") * -1

End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for. It iterates from row 5 to the last populated cell in Column L.

I think your `If` statement is reversed based on the body of the question, if that is not the case just change the `=` to `<>`.

```
Sub NewCode()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    With ws
        For i = 5 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row
            If UCase(.Cells(i, 12).Value) = "D" Then
                .Cells(i, 8).Value = .Cells(i, 8).Value * -1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using this code but nothing is happening in my file when I run through it...not sure why. Do i need to add something else to this code? I also tried changing the = to <> but the macro still didn't change any data

Comment: Do the cells contain only "D"?

Comment: Yeah the cells in column L only contain one letter....there's other cells in L that contain different letters like "R" or "C" but I only want the the numbers in row H to change to negative if the letter in column L is "D"

Comment: The sheet name is definitely "Sheet1" right? And the code was pasted into the workbook you're trying to run it from, not a personal binary file or something right?

Comment: Yes and correct. I just tried creating a new workbook with the same data and using the macro and it still didn't change any of the data

Comment: Then there is some difference in your data from what is in the body of the question. I can't say for sure what it is, but if you have numbers in column H and some Ds in column L this will work. Maybe you have trailing or leading whitespace?

Comment: I think I found the issue in the code (not sure how to fix it) When I run through to debug it, after the "for i = 5" line the code skips all next steps and goes to the "End With" line if that helps?

Comment: Then your data in Column L ends before row 5.

Comment: Sorry for the back and fourth, but something isn't right. I just updated my spreadsheet so that there is only "D" in every single cell in column L, and put numbers in every single cell in column H and the macro is still skipping over those steps

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have a sheet called sheet1 but that isn't the sheet that contains the data. There really isn't much in this code for it to go wrong, it's very basic. if you do `Debug.Print ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row` what does it return? Placed above the loop in the sub.

Comment: Nothing happened. I added select cell to the code to see if anything was working at all and it selected the cell i typed. Is there any other way of writing a similar code that would give the same outcome?

Comment: Isn't it just the negation of "D", i.e. any other letters like e.g. "C" (c.f. your original post where you multiply in the `Else` condition)? Furthermore could'nt it be a lowercase/uppercase issue defining a variable `D` instead of a 1-character string?

Comment: What do you mean nothing happened? That line must return a number between 1 and 1048576.

Comment: @T.M. it's not an upper/lowercase issue I don't think since the code and the sheet are using uppercase letters. Warcupine I put that "Debug" code in different areas of the code and nothing was returned.

Comment: ... then it might be the negation: `If UCase(.Cells(i, 12).Value) <> "D" Then` as suggested in my comment. - Btw Are you including `Option Explicit` in the declaration head of your code modules?

Comment: Do you have the immediate window open? @T.M. It will work with both upper and lower because of the `Ucase`.

Comment: Yes the only thing I have open is the one excel file, sheet 1. Every cell in column A-H is a random number now, and every cell in column J-O is "D" and the code isn't working for anything no matter what I try to change. It just keeps skipping over that part i mentioned before

Comment: a) The hint to case sensitivity referred to the (global?|suppressed?undeclared?) variable `D` in the original post as I it isn't explicitly a string in a "working" code. b) The other suggestion is that it's just a negation of `="D"` as the multiplication is executed only in the `Else` part. @Warcupine

Comment: I am going to try reposting the question and see if I can get any other ideas. Sorry for the time everyone :(

Comment: If the answers and related comments are helpful to (give you a start to) get to the wanted result, then it's not wasted time. If so consider to accept by ticking the green checkmark. @dh232391